# Python Code to find the average number of trials in single dice

Tags: python, for-loop, random, while-loop, dice

Write a Pseudo code in Python ,to find the average number of trials to obtain all the six sides of a die atleast once. For Example, if you roll a 6-sided dice for the first time, you can get any of the 6 sides (1,2,3,4,5,6). Let us say you get 3. When you roll it for the second time, you get 4. Now few rolls you got 5,2,3,1,6. You can stop rolling since you got all the six sides atleast once. Now, if you conduct this experiment for 10000 times. What is the average number of  rolls ?

Hey, i am kind of new to programming. I can understand that we need use for loop to make it for 10000 times.

And understood that when ever atleast all six sides appeared once , we will make that as set. so in ending when we calculate average of rolls, avg.of rolls = 10000/ (num of set).

I am able to implement , but i cannot make set (all six sides appeared ).... I tried to explain best way i could.Any Help would be appreciated ..

pseudo code for creating set

Comment: Nitpicking: The singular of `dice` (plural) is _die_.

Comment: _I am able to implement_ -> Please [edit] your question and show us what you have implemented so far.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must first understand and describe in natural language (plain English) how you are going to proceed.

Here you have said:

- we will conduct 10000 experiment
- an experiment consists in randomly rolling a die until the six sides have been found. The result of the experiment is the number of rolls

From that point, we must first modelize an experiment. To identify whether the six sides have been found, Python provides the `set` container: just count the number of rolls and for each roll, add the side to a set. When the size of the set is 6, we can stop the experiment, and we do have the number of rolls.

The next step will be to repeat 10000 time the experiment and cumulate the results. By dividing the sum by 10000 we will find an estimation of the average.